# SQL Server, Adding integers from separate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on an assignment that requires us to give out combinations and averages of different columns together and I'm having a little difficulty figuring out how to go about it. They're all number based columns, for example:

I have 4 columns of integers that need to be added into a 5th column but with a twist. Col 1's numbers are definite, but col 2, 3 and 4's numbers are multiplied (x2, x3, x4, respectively) and I'm genuinely not sure how to go about this.

I should mention that I'm in a view and not a table, so I'm unsure if I should have created this column when creating the view OR if there's some way to do it in a select statement.

Any help or tips appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So I've got 4 columns, right?

Col1= 179 Col2= 30 Col3= 3  Col4= 10

I need them combined into a new 5th column, but that math should looks something like:

(179 x1) + (30 x 2) + (3 x 3) + (10 x 4) = Column 5

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```
SELECT Col1
     , Col2
     , Col3
     , Col4
     , Col1 + (Col2 * 2) + (Col3 * 3) + (Col4 * 4) AS [Col5]
FROM YourTable
```